# Enable/Install unix socket stream in XAMPP PHP

Tags: php

Using XAMPP on Windows 7 64

In my `phpinfo()` 
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2

What I need 
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2

How to enable/install it on php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, unix sockets is just not work on Windows, even on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)